# YQL Fantasy Hockey - League Standings by Month?

Tags: yql

I'm trying to gather league standings by month (or a custom time period)
I know how to do it for a specific date but can't seem to find a way to do from x to y

Is this possible?  (other than repeating the query for each day I want)

Is is not a head to head or rotisserie league, just straight overall points.

*Edit:*

Example query:

[image]

Comment: Please post how you are doing it for a specific date.

Comment: Well you have to sign in to use the YQL console, but an example query is [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.leagues.scoreboard%20where%20league_key%3D%27238.l.178574%27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to fetch by month or for a date range. If you look at the YQL table [fantasysports.leagues.scoreboard](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=desc%20fantasysports.leagues.scoreboard), you can see the parameters only accept the optional `week` parameter. This matches the [Yahoo! Fantasy Sports API docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/league-resource.html) (search for 'scoreboard') which shows it can give results for the current week, or another specified week.

I think this is because the [Yahoo! Fantasy Sports](http://sports.yahoo.com/fantasy) scoreboards are all week-based, regardless of the actual frequency of games for the specific sport.

To capture scores by month, you can make several individual calls for each week.